# Sub query result in Django not looping from drop down select box

Tags: django, django-queryset

This is the error am getting:

**QuerySet.annotate() received non-expression(s): 17**

What I want is a subquery that will do something similar to the

```
select * from inecdb.announced_pu_results 
where polling_unit_uniqueid in
(
select uniqueid from polling_unit 
where lga_id = (select uniqueid from lga where uniqueid= 17) 
);
```

The subquery

```
obj3 = Pu_results.objects.filter(polling_unit_uniqueid__in=Subquery(Unit.objects.filter(lga_id=obj1)))
```

is not displaying any result please can any one help

This is my view

```
if request.method == 'POST':
    selected_item = request.POST.get('item_id') #This is from html select box 

    obj = Lga.objects.get(lga_id=selected_item)
    obj1 = obj.lga_id
    obj3 = Pu_results.objects.filter(polling_unit_uniqueid__in=Subquery(Unit.objects.filter(lga_id=obj1)))
    for obt in obj3:
        print(obt.party_score) #I want looping results here
```

This is my Model

```
from django.db import models
from django.urls import reverse
#from django.urls import reverse

class Unit(models.Model):
    uniqueid   = models.IntegerField(primary_key=True)
    polling_unit_id = models.IntegerField(blank=False)
    ward_id  = models.IntegerField(default=False)
    lga_id = models.IntegerField(default=False)
    uniquewardid = models.IntegerField(default=True)
    polling_unit_number = models.CharField(max_length=50, unique=True)
    polling_unit_name = models.CharField(max_length=51)
    #pulling_unit_number = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    polling_unit_description = models.CharField(max_length=300)
    lat = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    long = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    entered_by_user = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    date_entered = models.DateTimeField(blank=False)
    user_ip_address = models.CharField(max_length=50)


    def get_absolute_url(self):
        #return f"/products/{self.id}/"
        return reverse("polling:inec-pull-result", kwargs={"uniqueid": self.uniqueid})


class Lga(models.Model):
    uniqueid = models.AutoField(primary_key=True)
    lga_id = models.IntegerField()
    lga_name = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    state_id = models.IntegerField()
    lga_description = models.TextField(blank=True, null=True)
    entered_by_user = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    date_entered = models.DateTimeField()
    user_ip_address = models.CharField(max_length=50)

    class Meta:
        db_table = 'lga'

class Article(models.Model):
    title   = models.CharField(max_length=120)
    content = models.TextField()
    active  = models.BooleanField(default=True)
```

Comment: Show your model definition. Also why `POST`, not `GET`? And the whole filtering can be done with something like (can be wrong because I don't see models): `Pu_results.objects.filter(polling_unit_uniqueid__lga_id=selected_item, )`

Comment: Thank you I have added the model

Comment: what I want the view to do is similar to this raw subquery:---          select * from inecdb.announced_pu_results 
where polling_unit_uniqueid in
(
select uniqueid from polling_unit 
where lga_id = (select uniqueid from lga where uniqueid= 17) 
);

Comment: What is `Pu_results`? That's the model you're querying but you're not showing it to us. Also why are you models not using `ForeignKey` fields if they obviously refer to each other? Having `lga_id` as `IntegerField` to refer to `Lga` model defeats the purpose of using a SQL-type database!!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to make sure that the queryset you use for the subquery returns just one column, use `values()` for that. Note that `Subquery` isn't needed:

```
units = Unit.objects.filter(lga_id=obj1).values('uniqueid')

obj3 = Pu_results.objects.filter(polling_unit_uniqueid__in=units)
```

Read the documentation for the [`in` lookup](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/stable/ref/models/querysets/#in) for a more detailed explanation of passing a QuerySet to `in`.

Comment: Thank you for the answer. I also tried this and it work: obj3 = Pu_results.objects.filter(polling_unit_uniqueid__in=Subquery(Unit.objects.values('uniqueid').filter(lga_id=obj1)))

Answer (score 0):

This also works:

```
obj3 = Pu_results.objects.filter(
         polling_unit_uniqueid__in = Subquery(
           Unit.objects.values('uniqueid').filter(lga_id=obj1)
         )
       )
```